# Problema al recorrer un arraylist

Tags: java

estoy haciendo una aplicación que coge las palabras que se repitan de un texto  y las almacena en el arraylist "palabrasclave".El problema es que en en el arraylist palabrasclave cuando hago debug lo que contiene es todas las palabras repetidas.Creo que el problema esta en el algoritmo.Os dejo mi código para ver si alguien sabe de que se trata

```
for (int i = 0; i < palabras.size(); i++) {

        String palabraencuestion = palabras.get(i);

        for (int y = 0; y < palabras.size(); y++) {

            String palabra = palabras.get(y);

            if (palabraencuestion == palabra) {

                palabrasclave.add(palabraencuestion);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Que significa "que coge las palabras que se repitan de un texto y las almacene en el arraylist X"? Es guardar una vez cada palabra que se repite, o es guardar la palabra una vez y la cantidad de repeticiones, o es guardar la palabra tantas veces como se repite.

Comment: la instrucción `if (palabraencuestion == palabra)` esta mal implementada cuando usa el `==`esta comparando posiciones de memoria y no el contenido de la palabra, debe cambiarlo a `if (palabraencuestion.equals(palabra))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si recorres un array ejemplo={"ave","pez","gato","pez","perro", "ave", "ave"}; tu algoritmo devolverá= {"ave","pez","pez","ave","ave"}; lo que puedes hacer es pasar un "disctint" de java para limpiar el array resultante,

```
Set<String> temp = new LinkedHashSet<String>( Arrays.asList( palabrasclave ) );
String[] palabrasclavesinduplicados= temp.toArray( new String[temp.size()] );
```

o preparar el algoritmo para eliminar cada aparición de una palabra ya encontrada como duplicada y comenzar el bucle principal desde cero con el nuevo tamaño del array, pero no recomiendo esta última opción.

```
for (int i = 0; i < palabras.size(); i++) {
        String palabraencuestion = palabras.get(i);
        for (int y = 0; y < palabras.size(); y++) {
            String palabra = palabras.get(y);
            if (palabraencuestion == palabra && i!=y) {
                palabrasclave.add(palabraencuestion);
            }
        }
    }
```

agregando la siguiente condición `&& i!=y` evitarás que las palabras se comparen con ellas mismas.

Comment: Y en que lugar lo debería añadir?

Comment: Y, si pongo "ave pez gato pez perro ave ave" me devuelve "ave ave pez pez gato pez pez perro ave ave"

Comment: intenta añadirlo luego del for. deberias modificar el bucle interno para que no compare la palabraencuestion con ella misma.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método `contains()` para verificar si la palabra ya existe antes de agregarla. Por otro lado, me parece que no es necesario iniciar el segundo `FOR` desde cero, bien podría ser desde `i+1`.

Comment: No puedo usar solo un for porque si no se estaría comparando la misma palabra todo el rato